# C# insert Query

Tags: c#, sql

I am beginners in C#. Below insert query cannot insert value in my database,what is wrong with my code.

Is this code allow Null value in My database? If yes,

How to define `Null` value cannot store in my Database?

```
public void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmnd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Master WHERE Stockno = "+textBox1.Text+"";
    SqlDataReader dReader;
    dReader = cmnd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dReader.HasRows)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Stackno Already Exists!!");
    }
    else
    {
        dReader.Close(); 
        try
        {
            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("insert into Master Values(@Stockno,@Cost,@MRP,@[Item Desc],@Brand,@Style,@Shade,@Size");
            string s,c,m,i,p,b,st,sh,si; 
            s = textBox1.Text ;
            c = textBox2.Text  ;
            m = textBox3.Text  ;
            i = textBox4.Text  ;
            p = textBox5.Text ;
            b = textBox6.Text; 
            st= textBox7.Text; 
            sh= textBox8.Text; 
            si= textBox9.Text; 
            sc.Parameters.Add("@Stockno", s);  
            sc.Parameters.Add("@Stockno", c);
            sc.Parameters.Add("@Cost", m);
            sc.Parameters.Add("@MRP", i);
            sc.Parameters.Add("@[Item Desc]", p);
            sc.Parameters.Add("@Brand", b);
            sc.Parameters.Add("@Style", st);
            sc.Parameters.Add("@Shade", sh);
            sc.Parameters.Add("@Size", si);

            sc.Connection = con;           

            sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("saved");
        }
        catch (SqlException )
        {           
            MessageBox.Show("Enter full Details");  
        }
    }
    con.Close();    
}
```

Comment: Is there any exception?

Comment: Are your columns nullable in your database? Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: no..my columns are not nullable

Comment: I see @Stockno is substituted two times. :) Please share the exception

Comment: @user3840562: What is the exact problem here? is the code throws an error or you need to modify database to allow/not allow null values?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow `null` for your columns.

**Query Syntax:**

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ALTER COLUMN columnName dataType null
```

**Sample Code:**

```
ALTER TABLE Master ALTER COLUMN Style varchar(50) null
```

These are just sample values, replace the `columnName` and `data type` with original values.